# Matching ctrl-M character in Python

Tags: python

I am working on an interactive program where I take some actions based on the input. For the application I want to match `^M` characters in the input stream.

To do this I found the ASCII equivalent of `^M` which is `0xd` and converted the input character to ascii using `hex(ord(char))` and compared the two.

```
if hex(ord(char)) == 0xd:
    take_action()
```

But this condition never evaluates to true. To see if I am using the correct ascii values I wrote the input I am sending to a file.

```
 0xd
 0xd
 0xd
 0x65
 0x78
 0x69
 0x74
 0xd
 0x65
 0x78
 0x69
 0x74
 0xd
```

Could anyone tell me how to compare `^M` character and why the above does not work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xd` is an *integer literal* (it produces the value 13), but `hex()` returns a string. `'0xd'` may *look* like `0xd`, but are not equal:

```
>>> hex(13)
'0xd'
>>> 0xd
13
>>> hex(13) == 0xd
False
```

Remove the `hex()` call:

```
if ord(char) == 0xd:
```

or just use a string literal:

```
if char == '\x0d':
```

or the equivalent:

```
if char == '\r':
```

`'\r'` and `'\x0d'` produce the exact same character.

Comment: Is there a better way to match control characters?

Comment: @Sharad: that's too broad to answer; you didn't tell us much about your usecase or the rest of your code. It could be that `if '\r' in longerstring:` is a better option for your needs, or using a regular expression. But if you want to match an individual character, then using `char == '\r'` is the best way.

Comment: I actually do not receive ascii characters for all the cases. In case of a right arrow key I would see ^[[C instead of ASCII values. I was wondering how to handle these characters. '\r' works for new lines but I could not find equivalent for all the cases

Comment: @Sharad: Your terminal may be echoing the characters as ANSI escape sequences. Have you tried `print(repr(char))` to see what Python thinks it received? It'll give you a representation of the string that you can directly copy and paste into your code.